# puppet - define wildcard host in nodes.pp

Tags: linux, puppet

Is there a way to define wildcard hosts in puppetmaster´s nodes.pp

say i want all the hosts in one domain to receive a set of classes can i do something like:

```
# nodes.pp
#

node basenode {
  include  admina, adminb, admic
  }


node "*.acme.com" {
    include adminc
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not in this way.  You can create a 'default' node that will apply to any signed client.

```
node "default" {
   include foo
}
```

But you can only have 1 default.  If you want to replicate the functionality you describe you can use the external_nodes method of classification.  Basically you write a script that returns valid yaml when a client connects.  That script can do it anyway you want, check fqdn, query a db, hit ldap, etc.

Answer (score 16):

Regular expressions are now possible in Puppet 0.25, so what you want would be possible:

```
node /^(foo|bar)\.example\.com$/ {
include blah
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Few distros ship 0.25 as of yet, so in my Centos5 having 2.24.8 from the EPEL repo I had to do something like this for my worker nodes with hostnames like wn10.example.com:

```
node  default {
    $node_type = regsubst($hostname, '^([a-z]+).*$', '\1')
    case $node_type{
        wn: {include worker_node}
        default: {include generic_node}
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick update - puppet-2.6.12-1.el5.noarch is now available from EPEL (supports regular expressions in node names).